# Fortran COMMON block initialization

Tags: initialization, fortran, fortran-common-block

Fortran newbie here, I've been asked to work on an old Fortran codebase written in Fortran 77 with Salford/Silverfrost compiler (the original developer passed away).

The original developer uses named `COMMON` blocks extensively (to emulate global variables, AFAIU) and he uses `EQUIVALENCE` to (re-)initialize the blocks when needed like in this code snippet:

```
      IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)

      COMMON/COMMF2D/
     * ASCN(0:99,0:20,0:4)   
     *,FEMPTY2(8700)

      DIMENSION KLCKF2D(38400)
      EQUIVALENCE (KLCKF2D,ASCN)

      DO I= 1,38400                                              
      KLCKF2D(I)= 0
      END DO
```

Is this an acceptable programming practice or just a hack? Also, since I'm trying to port the code to GFortran, is it portable? (I understand that declarations like `REAL*8` are just hints to the compiler and not guaranteed)

Comment: Speaking about portability, no code that uses hardcoded constant values for type sizes (like `REAL*8`) or for type kinds (like `REAL(KIND=8)`) is portable. In portable Fortran 90+ code you should call `SELECTED_REAL_KIND()` in order to obtain a kind parameter that guarantees certain precision and exponential range.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`EQUIVALENCE` doesn't *do* anything, it certainly doesn't intialise anything, an `EQUIVALENCE` is a definition or declaration.  These days (and ever since the publication of the Fortran 90 standard with a force growing all the time) `EQUIVALENCE` is a hack, and should be avoided wherever possible.

The statement declares that 2 variables share storage (what the Fortran standards call *storage-association*).  One interpretation of this is that the names which are equivalenced are simply aliases, but the (ab-)use of the statement allows the programmer to do some other things which are regarded, by 21st century professional software engineers, as well-dodgy.

For example, and this applies in the snippet you've posted, `EQUIVALENCE` can be used to have variables of different types share the same storage.  You have an array called `ASCN` which is (implicitly) of type `REAL*8` equivalenced to an array called `KLCKF2D` which is (again implicitly) of type `INTEGER`.  What this means is that if you refer to the storage under one name the bit-patterns are interpreted as `REAL`s, using the other name they are `INTEGER`s -- and note that the bit pattern for a real with the value `100.0` will not (of course) be interpreted as the integer `100`.

And the hackery doesn't stop there.  One effect of the `COMMON` block declaration is to lay the variables out in memory, in your case the `10500 (= 100*21*5)` elements of `ASCN` are followed by the `8700` elements of `FEMPTY2`.  With a little multiplication and addition you find that `38400 = 2*(10500+8700)` which accords with the default integer size in this program being 4-bytes, ie half the size of the `REAL*8`s used in the other variables.  So the array `KLCKF2D` is larger than `ASCN` but the original programmer knew that the next `17400` bytes would be occupied by `FEMPTY2`.

So yes, this may be a way of setting all the bits in that part of your program's in-memory data to `0`, but it's (now considered to be) a horrid hack.  But it should be portable  -- successive Fortran standards have been very conservative about deleting obsolete features from the language and compiler-writers even more so, backward-compatibility is VERY important to Fortran programmers.

Oh, and to answer your question, yes `COMMON` blocks were (note the past tense) the FORTRAN77 way of declaring and using global variables.  These days the language offers the much safer option of declaring variables to be shared globally by wrapping them in a `MODULE` and `USE`-associating them.

I wouldn't have been surprised to see a line like

```
COMMON/COMMF2D/KLCKF2D(38400)
```

in your code, `COMMON` blocks can also be (ab-)used to rename and retype storage locations.

While I'm giving your old code a kicking, implicit typing is also frowned upon these days, far better to explicitly type all declarations.

Comment: Thanks @Mark! Yes, I know that `EQUIVALENCE` is just a declaration; poor wording on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Well, portable or not, the practice was ... common. (Earth humor. Ork. Ork.)
I'll give you an example: the data in the source code for the game Zork, which I've refurbished - it is virtually nothing but common blocks and equivalences. https://github.com/LydiaMarieWilliamson/zork-fortran

In the adjoining C translations, you will see how it plays out in C. The f2c translator has difficulty handling equivalences and common blocks (as you'll see in my translation log). My advice is set about to recode it all into C or C++, and fix it up there. That will make it more accessible to a larger variety of programmers. I'm preparing to do that with the entire LAPACK distribution (as you may have already noticed) - which is about 500000 to 1000000 lines.

The C equivalent to the structure, itself, is also the best way to set up multi-dimensional arrays. You allocate only one base segment for the whole thing. Then, for the second dimension, you allocate a segment of pointers into it - a raster. Then, for the third dimension, you allocate a segment of pointers into that ... and so on.

There is no good C equivalence for the equivalence statement, itself. (Earth humor. Ork. Ork.) Instead, an equivalent of equivalence is best found in C++ using reference types. In C++ you can also more directly render Fortran subscripting, since subscripting itself (with both [] and () type brackets) is a programmable operator. So, you could actually directly translate the equivalenced structure, and its indexing methods, as is -- as a static structure, without the need for the above-mentioned allocation.